# Xorg input device from a named pipe

Tags: keyboard, xorg, input-devices, pipe

I am trying to create a virtual input device that does a complex remapping of key presses of an existing keyboard. The remapped output stream is written to a named pipe which is supposed to serve as an input device for xorg.

Initially I tried to replace the file descriptor for an existing input device for Xorg. However seems like Xorg has some protection against ptrace and gdb, so I could not hack it successfully.

What I try now, is to configure Xorg in a way such that it treats my named pipe as yet another keyboard input stream and reads input from there. I would like to know if you had any similar experience ?

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion: What you are trying to achieve sounds like libevdev (or a binding like python-evdev) would be better suited. Alternatively, if you want to manipulate Xorg, I'd suggest Xlib.

Comment: Thanks that was a good reference